# Proper Perl syntax for complex substitution

Tags: regex, perl, syntax

I've got a large number of PHP files and lines that need to be altered from a standard 
`echo "string goes here";` syntax to: 
`custom_echo("string goes here");`

This is the line I'm trying to punch into Perl to accomplish this:
`perl -pi -e 's/echo \Q(.?*)\E;/custom_echo($1);/g' test.php`
Unfortunately, I'm making some minor syntax error, and it's not altering "test.php" in the least.  Can anyone tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Perl is not an acronym.

Comment: Actually, it is an acronym. But it is still spelled 'Perl'.

Comment: Actually, it is **not** an acronym. But there are several backronyms. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl#Name

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just do something like:

```
perl -pi -e 's|echo (\".*?\");|custom_echo($1);|g' file.php
```

I don't think `\Q` and `\E` are doing what you think they're doing. They're not beginning and end of quotes. They're in case you put in a special regex character (like `.`) -- if you surround it by `\Q ... \E` then the special regex character doesn't get interpreted.

In other words, your regular expression is trying to match the literal string `(.?*)`, which you probably don't have, and thus substitutions don't get made.

You also had your `?` and `*` backwards -- I assume you want to match non-greedily, in which case you need to put the `?` as a non-greedy modifier to the `.*` characters.

**Edit:** I also strongly suggest doing:

```
perl -pi.bak -e ... file.php
```

This will create a "backup" file that the original file gets copied to. In my above example, it'll create a file named `file.php.bak` that contains the original, pre-substitution contents. This is incredibly useful during testing until you're certain that you've built your regex properly. Hell, disk is cheap, I'd suggest always using the `-pi.bak` command-line operator.

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly what I was ham-handedly trying to get to.  And I always rsync my data before making any major changes like this. :)

Answer (score 2):

You put your grouping parentheses inside the metaquoting expression (`\Q(pattern)\E`) instead of outside (`(\Qpattern\E)`), so your parentheses also get escaped and your regex is not capturing anything.

Comment: Did you get inside and outside backwards?

Comment: Well, that's one less problem, but I still seem to have more issues.

Comment: @Matt Kane don't think so ... I meant this to parse as "You put them inside but you should have put them outside"

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize that the outer set of parens was not meant to part of code section.